# Why was the Göbekli Tepe question closed?

Tags: discussion

Why has [Is there plenty of historical evidence to show that the writers of the Bible, when talking of Eden, were describing Göbekli Tepe?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/16211/is-there-plenty-of-historical-evidence-to-show-that-the-writers-of-the-bible-wh) been closed?

@Oddthinking tells me that "You may have more luck with questions about "*what does the bible mean*" by asking at hermeneutics.stackexchange.com, where there are more biblical scholars.", but I'm not interested about hermeneutics. I'm only interested to know if there is plenty of historical evidence to show that the writers of the Bible, when talking of Eden, were describing Göbekli Tepe.

As per above reason I ask to the community to vote to reopen the question or, alternatively, I'd like to know a more expanded argument as to why the question has been closed. After all a claim was made!

Comment: I have no idea what is up for discussion here, I don't follow at all.

Comment: @Werti, what is unclear? Question is clear, apart the title being initially posted that was wrong. Please, clarify.

Comment: What is the claim you want examined?

Comment: @Sancho, the fact is that the journalist made this claim "there is plenty of historical evidence to show that the writers of the Bible, when talking of Eden, were describing Göbekli Tepe". Why would this be not a claim?

Answer (score 6):

Three different mods (including Sklivvz) commented on the question. Between the three of them, we have three different approaches to pointing out problems with the question.

I didn't close the question, so I can't give a categorical answer, but I can point out reasons why it shouldn't be reopened.

I pointed to Hermeneutics. Why? Because they study not just current interpretations of the Bible, but what the Bible historically referred to, in its original languages. If there is historical evidence that the story of Eden is about Göbekli Tepe, they would know about it. Conversely, if there is historical evidence for my crackpot theory that the story of Eden is about the beaches of Sydney instead, they would know about it. Or, if the story of Eden was actually constructed over several iterations, from several different pagan myths, making the very claim meaningless, they should know about it.

You make a semantic distinction: you are not interested whether his claim that Eden = Göbekli Tepe is true. You are interested whether his claim that there is lots of evidence that Eden = Göbekli Tepe is true. So a response proving that Göbekli Tepe is NOT Eden would be off-topic. The answer has to prove there is not a lot of evidence, instead. That seems like too subtle a distinction to make it a notable question, especially when the terms "lots of evidence" isn't a precise measure.

Ultimately, this complaint caused me to read the offending rubbish article. I concur with @Sancho. The author laid out the evidence over the next few paragraphs. Therefore, the answer to your question is *yes*, there *is* "lots of evidence". It is worthless evidence that, I am confident, would be overturned in Hermeneutics, but there is lots of it.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the author's sentence "there is plenty of historical evidence..." was meant only to introduce the subsequent five paragraphs, which is what I think he interprets as "plenty of historical evidence". He's not claiming that there is more historical evidence than he lays out himself. It's simply a stylistic choice in how he introduced that section of his article. So, it's purely subjective as to whether or not those five paragraphs constitute "plenty of historical evidence".

Answer (score 0):

The reason that is a poor question, is that the news is simply a bunch of speculation. The article does not make clear, disprovable statements we can deal with, for example said "evidence" is simply about the location or the name of the area in which the dig is. Hardly "plenty" of evidence, in my opinion, but we are discussing the meaning of "plenty" here.

Also, to ultimately answer the question, we should also prove or disprove what the authors of the Bible meant. Good luck with that :-)

The article doesn't even state that there is published research behind it. It seems to be a piece to advertise [the book at the bottom of the page](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Genesis-Secret-Tom-Knox/dp/0007284144), which is a fanta-archaeology piece a-la Dan Brown.

I personally did not close the question because I felt it was not good quality but (barely) answerable. Now that it's closed I'd leave it closed because it's really not that interesting to me.